# React can not read excel file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, file

I was using read-excel-file in my react application. The package was running fine last week but suddenly stopped working and giving error 'nodeType' error. I tried to reinstall the package but it is still not fixed. Tried to do a fresh install every thing but that still did not work. No help is available on the package site.

## Workbook.js

```
const Workbook = () => {

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const file = e.target.file.files[0]

    if(!file) return

    const rows = await readXlsxFile(file);

    console.log(rows);    }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
          <br/>
          <button type="submit">uplaod</button>
        </form>

        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Workbook
```